# Combo box to select city for time zone

Tags: android, combobox, timezone

I want to create a combo box to allow the user to select arbitrary cities around the world (not just the ones in the Java time zones) and/or start typing a city name and allow me to programmatically read the city name and time zone for a world clock app I am writing.

Is there an easy way to do this, preferably in a PreferenceScreen? Is there a useful database I can use for cities and a widget I can use for selection with substring search?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easy way to do this

Use an `AutoCompleteTextView`.

> preferably in a PreferenceScreen?

You will have to find or write your own `AutoCompletePreference` for this. The simplest would be to create a subclass of `DialogPreference`, perhaps cloning the implementation of `EditTextPreference` and replacing the `EditText` with an `AutoCompleteTextView`.